# Disassembly of a mixed ARM/Thumb2 ELF file

Tags: arm, disassembly, thumb

I'm trying to disassemble an ELF executable which I compiled using `arm-linux-gnueabihf` to target `thumb-2`. However, ARM instruction encoding is making me confused while debugging my disassembler. Let's consider the following instruction:

> mov.w fp, #0

Which I disassembled using `objdump` and `hopper` as a thumb-2 instruction.  The instruction appears in memory as `4ff0000b` which means that it's actually`0b00f04f` (little endian). Therefore, the binary encoding of the instruction is:

> 0000 1011 0000 0000 1111 0000 0100 1111

According to ARM architecture manual, it seems like ALL thumb-2 instructions should start with `111[10|01|11]`. Therefore, the above encoding doesn't correspond to any thumb-2 instruction. Further, it doesn't match any of the encodings found on section A8.8.102 (page 484).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing the subtle distinction that wide Thumb-2 encodings are not 32-bit words like ARM encodings, they are a pair of 16-bit halfwords (note the bit numbering above the ARM ARM encoding diagram). Thus whilst the halfwords themselves are little-endian, they are still stored in 'normal' order relative to each other. If the bytes in memory are `4ff0000b`, then the actual instruction encoded is `f04f 0b00`.

Answer (score 1):

thumb2 are extensions to the thumb instruction set, formerly undefined instructions, now some of them defined.  arm is a completely different instruction set.  if the toolchain has not left you clues as to what code is thumb vs arm then the only way to figure it out is start with an assumption at an entry point and disassemble in execution order from there, and even there you might not figure out some of the code.

you cannot distinguish arm instructions from thumb or thumb+thumb2 extension simply by bit pattern.  also remember arm instructions are aligned on 4 byte boundaries where thumb are 2 byte and a thumb 2 extension doesnt have to be in the same 4 byte boundary as its parent thumb, making this all that much more fun.  (thumb+thumb2 is a variable length instruction set made from multiples of 16 bit values)

if all of your code is thumb and there are no arm instructions in there then you still have the problem you would have with a variable length instruction set and to do it right you have to walk the code in execution order.  For example it would not be hard to embed a data value in .text that looks like the first half of a thumb2 extension, and follow that by a real thumb 2 extension causing your disassembler to go off the rails.  elementary variable word length disassembly problem (and elementary way to defeat simple disassemblers).

16 bit words A,B,C,D

if C + D are a thumb 2 instruction which is known by decoding C, A is say a thumb instruction and B is a data value which resembles the first half of a thumb2 extension then linearly decoding through ram A is the thumb instruction B and C are decoded as a thumb2 extension and D which is actually the second half of a thumb2 extension is now decoded as the first 16 bits of an instruction and all bets are off as to how that decodes or if it causes all or many of the following instructions to be decoded wrong.

So start off looking to see if the elf tells you something, if not then you have to make passes through the code in execution order (you have to make an assumption as to an entry point) following all the possible branches and linear execution to mark 16 bit sections as first or additional blocks for instructions, the unmarked blocks cannot be determined necessarily as instruction vs data, and care must be taken.

And yes it is possible to play other games to defeat disassemblers, intentionally branching into the second half of a thumb2 instruction which is hand crafted to be a valid thumb instruction or the begnning of a thumb2.

fixed length instruction sets like arm and mips, you can linearly decode, some data decodes as strange or undefined instructions but your disassembler doesnt go off the rails and fail to do its job.  variable length instruction sets, disassembly at best is just a guess...the only way to truly decode is to execute the instructions the same way the processor would.